# Do pyperclip3 or pasteboard support paste of PNG on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pyperclip, pasteboard

I am trying to figure out how to paste a PNG graphic from the clipboard into a Python script on macOS.  I have looked into using the pyperclip, pyperclip3, and pasteboard modules.  I cannot get any of these to work.  I am able to paste text from the clipboard, but not PNG.

The project description for [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) explicitly states that it is for copy/paste of text data.

The overview for [pyperclip3](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip3/) states that it has cross-platform support for both text and binary data.  It also states that it is using pasteboard as the backend for MacOS.

There is a caveat in the description of the `get_contents` function in [pasteboard](https://pypi.org/project/pasteboard/) that states:

> type - The format to get. Defaults to pasteboard.String, which corresponds to NSPasteboardTypeString. See the pasteboard module members for other options such as HTML fragment, RTF, PDF, PNG, and TIFF. Not all formats of NSPasteboardType are implemented.

It does not, however, give any indication of which formats may or may not actually be implemented.

Here is the complete script from my attempts to make pasteboard work:

```
import pasteboard
pb = pasteboard.Pasteboard()
x = pb.get_contents(type=pasteboard.PNG)
print(type(x))
print(x)
```

If I drop the type argument from get_contents and there is text in the clipboard, this works as expected.  If I keep the `type=pasteboard.PNG` argument and there is PNG data in the clipboard, the output shows that the type of x in `NoneType`

And this is the complete script from my attempts to make pyperclip3 work:

```
import pyperclip3
x = pyperclip3.paste()
print(type(x))
print(x)
```

In this case it doesn't matter if I have text or PNG data in the clipboard, the type of x is `bytes`.  For text, the content of x is as expected.  For PNG data, the content of x is the empty byte string.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  Or am I wasting my time trying to figure out how to make pasting of PNG data into a python script work?

Comment: Pyperclip3 has moved to [pyclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyclip/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the type attribute that is needed by `pasteboard` is `public.tiff`,  not `Pasteboard.PNG`.  With that, I was able to capture PNG data from the clipboard into a PIL Image via `pb.get_contents()`

Answer (score -1):

[PIL.Imagegrab.grabclipboard()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html#PIL.ImageGrab.grabclipboard) also exists to grab an image from the clipboard!

Comment: That's not what the question asks about, though. This should be a comment, if even that.

Comment: Despite the title, the question seems more interested in successfully accomplishing the pasting than in what library or method is used, so this seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @tripleee MikeMayer67 mentions multiple different libraries, trying to find something that will work for them, specifically: _Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Or am I wasting my time trying to figure out how to make pasting of PNG data into a python script work?_  Figured this would make things better for the next guy.